# Make Twitter recognize the <enter> key to post tweets?

Tags: twitter, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to make the <kbd>enter</kbd> key submit a tweet automatically on Twitter?

If so, how?

Comment: It would be very simple to create a browser extension to do this. Tell me what browser you use and I'll start in a few hours

Comment: @JJ56 - I primarily run Chrome and Firefox .. and an extension would be very cool :)

Comment: @JJ56 - were you able to get an extension made that would do this? I could see that being hyper-useful in the community :)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get around to it, forgot about it, and have been on holiday for the last week. I will do it, I promise :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to use <kbd>enter</kbd> to submit the new tweet on Twitter.com. By default it creates a line break, even if line breaks are not displayed by Twitter.com and most apps.

The fastest way to post a tweet using your keyboard is the following:

1. Press <kbd>n</kbd> for new tweet on your Twitter home page
2. Write your tweet content
3. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd> to post it

Comment: <alt> then <enter> is not working in Chrome :\

Comment: Sorry @warren, my fault. I was thinking to tab and wrote alt, don't know why. Press TAB and then ENTER to post the tweet you are composing.

Comment: Would Control+Enter work? Enter and Control+Enter often interchangeably share the submit/new line functionality. I don't use Twitter so I can't check myself.

Comment: @Phong No that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution I came up with (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283923/greasemonkey-with-jquery-how-to-write-the-greasemonkey-script-to-modify-page-do)).  You can download the full Greasemonkey script [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/131145).

```
setInterval (function() { checkForTweetbox (); }, 500);

function checkForTweetbox () {
    var tweetbox = document.querySelector ('div.tweet-box textarea');   //check for new tweet window
    if (tweetbox) {
        if (! tweetbox.weHaveProcessed) {
            tweetbox.weHaveProcessed    = true;
//          alert ('New tweet-box found!');
        }
    }   
    tweetbox.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){                                        //13 = Enter keycode
            document.querySelector ('a.primary-btn').click();           //there must be at least one character in the textarea  
        }
    }           
}
```